# Google analytics: UserId and e-commerce correlation

Tags: google-analytics

I have a user in google analytics with a couple of custom dimensions set. This user also have a userId (`uid`) set in google analytics. Now I'm sending an Ecommerce transaction setting this very userId when sending, but when I'm later looking at the ecommerce transactions that have happened I can't see any of the custom dimensions that this userId should have.

I assume I should be able to see all the data connected to this `uid`. What's the best way to debug this? Or am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Just to be clear, you have the UserID set into a custom dimension (I assume at the User scope), and some other custom dimensions as well. How have you scoped your other custom dimensions?